# Understanding the proofs in "Elementary aspects of the Verlinde formula and of the Harder–Narasimhan–Atiyah–Bott formula" from Don Zagier

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, gauss-sums

As the proofs of Theorem 1 in "elementary aspects of the Verlinde formula and of the Harder-Narasimhan-Atiyah-Bott formula" are very terse I could not understand all proofs. The paper can be found at https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/mpim/94-5/fulltext.pdf.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the proofs of (v), (vi) und (ix). I could also not find the multiplication law for the cotangent function used in (ii). In the proof of (iii) I could not understand how $V_h(k)$ is rewritten, how it is known that $\frac{k}{\tan kx}=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-4)^sB_{2s}}{(2s)!}n^{2s}x^{2s-1}$, how the standard partial fraction decomposition of $\cot x$ gives the result which follows, how to perform induction to show that $\sin^{-2h}$ is a linear combination of $f_{i}(x)$ and how (iii) is rewritten in the proof for (iv). I could also not undertand how the result of (iv) follows from the proof as the expression from (vi) is nowhere to be found in the proof of (vi).

Also I could not come up with alternative formulas for odd negative power sums of $\sin x$. Some tips would be helpful.

Sorry for being dumb :/

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: Why don't you give this reference: https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/mpim/94-5/fulltext.pdf ?

Comment: I see no real reason to close this well formulated question.

Comment: About the formula for $\dfrac{k}{\tan(kx)}$, one finds [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function) this formula: $
\cot x ={\frac {1}{x}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac {(-1)^{n}B_{2n}(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the reference. Thanks for answering part of my question!